# I've "Reset this PC" in a macOS Bootcamp installation of Windows and have lost the ability to sign into macOS

Tags: windows, macos, boot-camp

After installing Windows 10 on my Macbook via Bootcamp, I've "Reset this PC" while in Windows, and now I'm no longer able to reboot into macOS.

I'm not concerned with losing any files on this computer (in either OS), but I would like to reinstall macOS, and then reinstall Windows via Bootcamp.

How would one go about this?

Comment: What happens if you hold Opt at boot? You've probably just lost the additional Boot Camp drivers, so Windows can't see the Mac's APFS disk any more.

Comment: Sweet, yeah, I tried holding `option` at boot and was able to log into macOS. Now, I'll try to use Bootcamp to remove and recreate the Windows partition. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to post a formal answer here 

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-install the entire Windows partition. BCA will let you get the drivers independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the reset has deleted the specific Boot Camp drivers which enable Windows to see the APFS file structure & make changes to the startup disk.

Holding Opt at boot ought to let you switch to macOS from where you should be able to run the Boot Camp Assistant & download the drivers again.
See [Apple KB - Download and install Windows support software on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204923) for further details